# is it possible to make a proxy with file_get_contents() or cURL?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I've just been messing around with `file_get_contents()` at school and have noticed, it allows me to open websites in school that are blacklisted.

Only a few issues:

No images load

Clicking a link on the website just takes me back to the original blocked page.

I think i know a way of fixing the linking issue, but haven't really thought it through..
 I could do a `str_replace` on the content from `file_get_contents` to replace any link, with another `file_gets_contents(`) function, on that link...right?

Would it make things easier if i used cURL instead?

Is what I'm trying to do, even possible, or am i just wasting my *valuable* time?

I know this isn't a good way to go about something like this, but, it is just a thought, thats made me curious.

Comment: +1 for testing and observing things :-) It shows you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a trivial task. It is possible, but you would need to parse the returned document(s) and replace everything that refers to external content so that they are also relayed through your proxy, and that is the hard part.

Keep in mind that you would need to be able to deal with (for a start, this is not a complete list):

- Relative and absolute paths that may or may not fetch external content
- Anchors, forms, images and any number of other HTML elements that can refer to external content, and may or may not explicitly specify the content they refer to.
- CSS and JS code that refers to external content, including JS that modifies the DOM to create elements with `click` events that act as links, to name but one challenge.

This is a fairly mammoth task. Personally I would suggest that you don't bother - you probably are wasting your *valuable* time.

Especially since some nice people have already done the bulk of the work for you:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/knproxy/

;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your "problem" comes from the fact that HTTP is a [stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) and different resources like css, js, images, etc have their own URL, so you need a request for each. If you want to do it yourself, and not use php-proxy or similar, it's "quite trivial": you have to clean up the html and normalize it with [tidy](http://at.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php) to [xml](http://at.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.php) (xhtml), then process it with [DOMDocument](http://at.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) and [XPath](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

You could learn a lot of things from this - it's not overly complicated, but it involves a few interesting "technologies".

What you'll end up with what is called a **crawler** or **screen scraper**.